# Can't setup DDNS for SSH (No-IP)

Tags: linux, router, ssh, ddns, noip

I wanted to set up the DDNS so I could connect to my Linux Mint machine via SSH remotely. For SSH traffic I want port 8291 because my ISP does not block it (checked with [portchecktool](http://www.portchecktool.com/)). I've already modified the sshd_config to listen on this port and locally it works perfectly. I've also configured my local router so it forwards the traffic to this port on my machine (which has static IP btw). As I meant before, in LAN SSH works just perfectly.

#### DDNS

If it comes to DDNS, I'm using the NO-IP one and I've downloaded and configured their Dynamic Update Client because my TP-LINK router hasn't got them on the list of DDNS providers as they recommended in [this](https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/how-to-configure-ddns-in-router/) guide. I've tested it already and it works fine according to the guide I've previously specified.
I can ping my hostname without problems (because it's simply my ISP's address).
However, I can't manage to connect to it via SSH. 
I've also tried to capture some traffic with Wireshark but it didn't intercept ANYTHING when my friend was trying to connect via SSH to my machine. I don't know what to do, I've spent already almost 2 days in order to get things work. If you have any idea what I can be doing wrong, any help would be appreciated. Also if you want any configuration files or screenshots I can show you, no problem.

Comment: What are the first two octets of the IP address assigned to your router's WAN interface?

Comment: Those are 192.168

Comment: If that is from the WAN interface, then your ISP is assigning you a private address and using NAT. That means that you cannot forward ports on the public address because you have no way to configure the router with the public address. In your residential ISP agreement, there is a clause prohibiting you from running servers to the public Internet, so your ISP really doesn't care that you cannot do that.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, I'll try another way